# Why is the graph that keeps track of my progress not up to date?

Tags: bug, questions, profile-page

Since the incident a week ago where I lost 100 points, my graph is still not up to date and doesn't take that into account.

Is this a bug?

Comment: I was not able to help

Comment: It doesn't matter, I got my points back just by being more active than over the past 3-4 months.